# ActiveAdmin AJAX autorefreshing partial

Tags: ajax, activeadmin, reload, renderpartial

I just have a simple index page which shows all the items of an ActiveRecord. 
What I'd like to have is that the table containing the items gets automatically refreshed every X seconds (i.e. loaded from the DB and rendered).
I already redefined the index action as a partial rendering

```
[app/admin/item.rb]
ActiveAdmin.register Item do
   index do   
      render :partial => "items_list"
   end
end
```

And then I have

```
[app/views/admin/items/_items_list.html.erb]
```

(I don't mind using ERB or ARB to write the partial)
The list table is rendered correctly when I first load the page.

I'm not sure which Javascript I should include in the page to refresh the list every X seconds. More specifically, which URL should be called by the Javascript command?
Do I need to define any custom action in the controller?

Thank you for any advice.

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed it.

```
[app/admin/item.rb]
ActiveAdmin.register Item do
   ...
   index do
      # do nothing; table will be filled with a partial via Javascript
   end

   collection_action :items_list do 
      @items = Item.all
  render :partial => "items_list"
   end
end

[app/views/admin/_items_list.html.arb]
table_for items do 
    column "attr_1"
    column "attr_2"
    column "attr_3"
end

[app/assets/javascripts/items.js]
$(document).ready( function() {
   setInterval(function(){
    $('#index_table_items').load('items/items_list');},1000);
   })
```

finally append to `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js` the following

```
//= require inbox_files
```

This way I get the list table updated every second. Also the CSS doesn't get distorted.